# Avconv -g parameter description

Tags: avconv

This is the official description of parameter:

```
‘-g[:stream_specifier] integer (output,video)’
set the group of picture (GOP) size
```

Not very informative I'd say.

Can anyone explain what does it actually do and what is the optimal value?

And on what depends moov atom size?

Answer (score 4):

#### GOP:

The video quality and compression ratio depends on *[Group of Pictures (GOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures)* structure. GOP structure also affects the distortion sensitivity of the video stream due to packet losses.

Increasing the GOP length, also increases the video quality. But after reaching the highest *[PSNR (Peak Signal to Noise Ratio)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)*, it starts to decrease. In the first increasing period, the efficient coding plays major role, so higher of GOP lengths lead to a better quality. After the optimal of GOP settings, when the video quality is the highest, the error propagation effect becomes more significant. Hence, using higher *[Intra frame (I-frame or Key frame)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)* intervals, the error will be spreading because of significant distortion.<sup>[Source](http://psrcentre.org/images/extraimages/113091.pdf)</sup>

***Each type of video has different optimal GOP, depend on its characteristic.***

---

#### Key Frame and Animation:

Videos or moving images - we're just tricking our minds; they're just still images displayed at a rapid succession! And the illusion gets better and smoother if the next frame appears at/before `1/25`<sup>th</sup> of a second which is the Human eye afterimage persistance time interval and the reason for [motion perception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_perception).

Illustration 1: <sup>(source: Wikipedia)</sup>

[image: keyFrame]

<sub>Fig: A sequence of video frames, consisting of two keyframes (I), one forward-predicted frame (P) and one bi-directionally predicted frame (B).</sub>

*(You may note that, in the above image the value of GOP, `-g` is 3, one key-frame with two supplimentary frames.)*

Illustration 2: <sup>(source: Wikipedia)</sup>

[image: animation]

<sub>Fig: A very simple animation created by key-framing. The animation lacks smoothness because each frame is completely independent of any other frame.</sub>

---

A possible Q&A:

**Q.** Aren't key frames enough? Why would we need to have the supplimentary/intermediate *P-frames, B-frames*?

**A.** Yes... but the use of such intermediate frames allow to reduce the overall size of the file (video).

---

For *better quality* video/streaming, you'd look to use low compression ratio but high frame rate which means high `-g` value with `avconv` (optimum GOP value is nearly half the value of *frames/sec*). As evident, the value for `-g` will have to be specified based on the *coders, compression ratio, frame rates* that you're using for the transcoding/streaming purpose; it's a relative quantity so there's no general value you can use with all inputs.

According to [this link](http://documentation.apple.com/en/compressor/usermanual/index.html#chapter=18&section=5&tasks=true) *the value of GOP for most media would be about half the value of frame rate* so that the key frame would be about *`0.5` seconds* apart and would produce a good quality video. We may also note that [other link](http://psrcentre.org/images/extraimages/113091.pdf) shows the PSNR attains a constant value at around half the test frame rate as indicated in the graph plot.

[image: snap1]

But the optimal value seems to lie around ***`1/6`<sup>th</sup> to `1/4`<sup>th</sup>*** the test frame rate.

And yeah, so you should be looking to use `-g` value around or in the range ***`1/6`<sup>th</sup> to `1/4`<sup>th</sup>*** so that the key frames appear every *`0.17` to `0.25` seconds*; and probably comment to improve the answer :)

---

References:

- [Group of pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures)
- [Video compression picture types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)
- [GOP Length
  Effect
  Analysis on H.264/AVC
  Video
  Streaming
  Transmission Quality
  over LTE Network](http://psrcentre.org/images/extraimages/113091.pdf)

Comment: So... the -g is the controller for the GOP value?

Comment: @Braiam, I've update the answer to include some more on the GOP value selection..

Answer (score 1):

You have several examples of usage on the [official avconv documentation](https://libav.org/avconv.html).

From [Section Tips](https://libav.org/avconv.html#Tips):

```
avconv -g 3 -r 3 -t 10 -b 50k -s qcif -f rv10 /tmp/b.rm
```

> If your computer is not fast enough, you can speed up the compression at the expense of the compression ratio. You can use ’-me zero’ to speed up motion estimation, and ’-g 0’ to disable motion estimation completely (you have only I-frames, which means it is about as good as JPEG compression).

Comment: So, what the -g means?

Comment: After some internet queries, I don't know. I guess the best place to ask this question (and expect a useful answer) is the [Libav mailing lists](https://libav.org/contact.html). They also have an [IRC channel](irc://irc.freenode.net/libav).